# How to structure the series correctly for a Highcharts drill-down

Tags: php, json, mysqli, highcharts

First I do not know if the title of my question is worthy of giving an answer so I thought about it enough to formulate it I hope I can count on someone's support. I have the following code, I need to show in the first level years (x axis) and a number (y axis) at the moment is just a test mode, in the second level I want to show departments (x axis) and a number (y axis) For this I have a three related tables that involve the aforementioned.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i7Nb.jpg)

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBBGg.jpg)
[Relational table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgiKr.jpg)

I show you the basis to give you a bigger picture, not because the truth is that I have it under control and it does not give me problems.

The problem is to show the values of that table in a demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown so far I have no problems to show the first level but to go deeper into the second level I I've run into the problem of how to create the series so it can be displayed. This is what I have in console shows me the first level but I know I have something wrong in the drilldown series but I do not know what it could be.

I leave the code that I am using.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Practica</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
 <script src="js/exporting.js"></script>
 <script src="js/export-data.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/data.js"></script>
 <script src="js/drilldown.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Practica. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },
    <?php  
        include 'conexion/conexion.php';
        $query = "
            SELECT 
            r.var_numerador_mujeres_casadas,
            a.mujeres_anio_casadas 
            FROM resumen_mujeres_casadas r 
            INNER JOIN mujeres_anios_casadas a ON r.id_mujeres_anios_casadas = a.id_mujeres_anios_casadas
        ";

        $query2 = "
            SELECT 
                r.var_denominador_mujeres_casadas, 
                a.mujeres_anio_casadas, 
                d.nombre_departamento 
            FROM 
                resumen_mujeres_casadas r 
            INNER JOIN departamentos_mujeres_casadas d
                 ON r.id_departamento = d.id_departamento 
            INNER JOIN mujeres_anios_casadas a 
                ON r.id_mujeres_anios_casadas = a.id_mujeres_anios_casadas 
            ORDER BY nombre_departamento ASC
        ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $query);
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $query2);

        if ($result && $result2) 
        {
            $arrayData= array();
            $arrayData2=array();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
            {
                array_push($arrayData, array(
                    "name"         => $row['mujeres_anio_casadas'],
                    "y"            => (int)$row['var_numerador_mujeres_casadas'],
                    "drilldown"    => $row['mujeres_anio_casadas']
                ));        
            }

            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
            {
                
                array_push($arrayData2,array(
                    "name"  => $row2['nombre_departamento'],
                    "id"    => $row2['mujeres_anio_casadas'],
                    "data"     => (int)$row2['var_denominador_mujeres_casadas']
                ));
                
            }

        }//FIN DEL IF RESULT
    ?>
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        data: <?php print $var = json_encode($arrayData); ?>
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: <?php print $var2 = json_encode($arrayData2); ?>//FIN DE TODA LA SERIE PARA EL DRILLDOWN
    }//FIN DEL DRILLDOWN, POR LO QUE HEMOS VISTO ESTO SERA EL LIMITE
});
</script>
```

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jig9U.jpg)

[grafica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL2ku.jpg)

Comment: Firstly: `drilldown.series` should be an array. Secondly: Your data is not parsed properly e.g.: there's `"data["`property instead of `"data"`.

Comment: You can give me a guide a little more explained I have 5 days already with this, I know that the drilldown.series of the second level has a different format but with json_encode I live a series that does not affect me the drilldown.series

Comment: Here's a demo that uses the proper JSON format: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s2bpwvxL/ You may find it helpful. Unfortunately I don't know much about PHP - it seems that `json_encode` messes up your data.

Comment: No, but thank you very much for the contribution, as well as unfortunately you do not master PHP and I do not dominate the hundred highcharts. I have searched a long time for a solution that the json of the second level is the one that is aruinandio everything but the truth and seek until more not able in several places and all gives solution but only to the first level of the drilldown